# How to validate Form using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, onsubmit

I'm trying to validate a forum sing  js, but it doesn't work at all. I tried everything, I used get element and using the form id thing, but still it doesn't working.

this is the Code:

```
function check()
        {
            var name= document.getElemeentById('name');
            var fname= document.insc.Prenom.value;
            var gender=document.insc.gender;
            var user = document.insc.user.value;
            var phone=document.insc.tel.value;
            var userT=document.insc.choice.selectedIndex;
            var pwd=document.insc.pwd.value;
            var email=document.insc.email.value;
            //name
            if (name.value ==null || name.value == '')
            {
                alert('name required');
                document.insc.name.focus();
                return false;
            }
            //la9ab
            if (fname == null || fname =='') 
            {
                alert('Family Name required');
                document.insc.Prenom.focus();
                return false;
            }
            //sexe
            if (gender[0].checked = false || gender[1].checked= false) 
            {
                alert('pick your Gender');
                return false;
            }
            //user
            if (user == null || user=='') 
            {
                alert('user required');
                document.insc.user.focus();
                return false;
            }
            //phone
            if (isNotNum(phone) && phone =='' && phone.length==8)
             {
                alert('Phone number required');
                document.insc.tel.focus();
                return false;
             }
             //pasword
            if (pwd =='' && pwd.length<=8 ) 
            {
                alert('password too short');
                document.insc.pwd.focus();
                return false;
            } 
            //user type
            if (userT[0] || userT='')
            {
                alert('select user type');
                document.insc.choice.focus();
                return false;
            }
            var atpos =email.indexOf('@');

            var dotpos =email.lastIndexOf('.');

            if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=email.length)

            {
                    alert('email is wrong');
                    document.insc.choice.focus();
                    return false;
            }

        }
    </script>

    <title>Inscription</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <form action="/" method="GET"  name="insc"  id="form" onsubmit="return check();">
        <div>
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" >
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="Pname">Family Name </label>
            <input type="text" id="Pname" name="Prenom" >
        </div>
        <div >Birthday Date</div>
        <div >
        <input type="Date" name="date" id="date">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="Gender"  >Sexe</label>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" id="H" value="Men" >Men
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" id="F" >Woman
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="User">User Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="User" name="User">
        </div>
        <div >
            <label for="tel">phone</label>
            <input type="text" id="tel" name="tel">
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="email">E-mail</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" >
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="Pwd">Password</label>
            <input type="Password" id="pwd" name="pwd">
        </div>
        <div >
            <label for="choice">User Type</label>
            <select id="choice" name="choice" >
                <option selected></option>
                <option value="client">client</option>
                <option value="provider">provider</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <button type="Submit" name="Envoyer" value="Envoyer" >Send</button>
        <input type="button" name="Delete" value="Delete" onclick="rform(); return false">
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

please help me to make it work because i stuck on these and i want to move on so i can progress in my own work thanks in advance

Comment: Take a deep look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation

Comment: You already have specified the input fields as `required` and added the acceptable value pattern. So, when you submit the form, it will automatically validate those fields. The first field `name` is the missing pattern. You don't need any script for that. Now, coming to your custom validation, access values using `document.getElementById('id`).value for text fields. For radio button it is different. And then perform your desired validation which is not covered by default form validation.

Comment: For starters, program defensively, this means check everything and don't assume you have done it correctly, for example, when you call getElementByID, always check the return is not undefined before use.  Also, use the typeof keyword to check that something is the type you expect it to be for example name, if ( name != undefined && typeof name == "object" ) {

Comment: you should have a check on each field while filling up the values and then for all values before submit. Instead of doing `document.insc` for each field, good practice is, `var fields = document.insc` and then access the values using `fields variable`.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things you have to check:

- `HTML` `form` validation is used by you with acceptable value patterns. This works without any `Javascript`. Why do you want to do custom validation?
- Having said that, you may still want to perform some custom validations. So, there is a case for that.
- To switch off `HTML` `form` validation in `form` use `novalidate`. In that case, you have to rely on custom validation. Otherwise, both default `HTML` `form` validation and custom validations will take place.
- In `check()` function access values using `document.getElementById('id').value` or `document.getElementsByName('name')`

Here is your modified code where I have turned off default form validation (you may turn it on by removing `novalidate` from `form`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Click Events</title>
    <script>
        function check() {
            var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
            var fname = document.getElementById("Pname").value;
            var gender = document.getElementsByName("gender");
            var user = document.getElementById("User").value;
            var phone = document.getElementById("tel").value;
            var userT = document.getElementById("choice").selectedIndex;
            var pwd = document.getElementById("pwd").value;
            var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
            //name
            if (name == undefined || name == '') {
                alert('name required');
                document.insc.name.focus();
                return false;
            }
            //la9ab
            if (fname == undefined || fname == '') {
                alert('Family Name required');
                document.insc.Prenom.focus();
                return false;
            }
            //sexe
            if (gende = undefined || (gender[0].checked == false && gender[1].checked == false)) {
                alert('pick your Gender');
                return false;
            }
            //user
            if (user == undefined || user == '') {
                alert('user required');
                document.insc.user.focus();
                return false;
            }
            //phone
            if (phone == undefined || phone == '' || phone.length != 8) {
                alert('Phone number required');
                document.insc.tel.focus();
                return false;
            }
            //pasword
            if (pwd == undefined || pwd == '' || pwd.length < 8) {
                alert('password too short');
                document.insc.pwd.focus();
                return false;
            }
            //user type
            if (userT == undefined || userT == '' || userT == 0) {
                alert('select user type');
                document.insc.choice.focus();
                return false;
            }

            if (email == undefined || email == '') {
                alert('email is required');
                return false;
            }
            var atpos = email.indexOf('@');

            var dotpos = email.lastIndexOf('.');

            if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= email.length) {
                alert('email is wrong');
                document.insc.choice.focus();
                return false;
            }

        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="/" method="GET" name="insc" id="form" onsubmit="return check(); return false;" novalidate>
        <div>
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required pattern="[a-zA-Z]{3-12} ">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="Pname">Family Name </label>
            <input type="text" id="Pname" name="Prenom" required pattern="[a-zA-Z]{3-12} " maxlength="12">
        </div>
        <div>Birthday Date</div>
        <div>
            <input type="Date" name="date" id="date" required max="12-31-2011" min="12-31-1960">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="Gender">Sexe</label>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" id="H" value="Men" required>Men
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" id="F" required>Woman
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="User">User Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="User" name="User" pattern="[a-zA-Z]{3-12}" maxlength="12" required>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="tel">phone</label>
            <input type="text" id="tel" name="tel" pattern="[0-9]{8}" maxlength="8" required>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="email">E-mail</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="Pwd">Password</label>
            <input type="Password" id="pwd" name="pwd" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9/*.!:;, ?.]{3-15}" maxlength="15" required>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="choice">User Type</label>
            <select id="choice" name="choice" required>
                <option selected></option>
                <option value="client">client</option>ß
                <option value="provider">provider</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <button type="Submit" name="Envoyer" value="Envoyer">Send</button>
        <input type="button" name="Delete" value="Delete" onclick="rform(); return false">
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```